# Online Hosting Functions

Tags: javascript, function, puppeteer

So I Basically want to host my puppeteer function online so that I works 24/7 even if I shutdown my computer. Actually it's a function that's called every 1 and half hour and so I want it to be able to run even if my computer is off that's why I want to host it online

Is there any free plan to use ?
thx for your help

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can use a free plan on Heroku, but you can also use free plan firebase functions and execute it for example by requests from updown.io.

Any of these services have extensive tutorials and examples.

On StackOverflow, there is not recommended commercial products promotions so I advice you to learn about:

- serverless
- vps
- cron
- cron sass services

Answer (score 0):

You can create a free Heroku account and try to host your cloud function in there. Also you can try creating a Google Firebase project and using their Cloud Functions API. Either way should work. Just keep in mind that after your free trial has expired on Firebase you wont be able to use cloud functions and you'll have to pay